Timefold from getJustificationList() to getJustification()
I have the following code with the deprecated method getJustificationList(). How can I do the same with getJustification()?
    Employee employee = null;
    int weekIndex = -1;
    List<SleepTimeWithDate> listOfSleepTimeWithDate = null;
    for (Object obj : constraintMatch.getJustificationList()) {
      if (obj instanceof Employee) {
        employee = (Employee) obj;
      } else if (obj instanceof List) {
        listOfSleepTimeWithDate = (List<SleepTimeWithDate>) obj;
      } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        weekIndex = (int) obj;
      }
    }
    ```


Okay, I got it. Its constraintMatch.getIndictedObjectList()

Justifications and indictments are two separate things.

A justification typically comes from the Constraint Streams as a single user-defined object. It can include indictments, but it can also include any other data. A justification is designed to bring semantics to constraint matches, and to serialize well into JSON.
Indictments, on the other hand, are typically a collection of assorted objects which have - in one way or another - contributed to that constraint match.

The code snippet you show suggests to me that you are using a old and not entirely public API for reading constraint matches. For a fully supported backwards-compatible API which deals with justifications, please see score analysis in Timefold Solver documentation.
